# Is There Any Location Specific in Apache2

Tags: apache2, apache

I'm using **Apache2** running on **Ubuntu-12.04** machine and I run my files through apache2 pointing to my folder in the local file system like

```
$ cd etc/apache2/ 
$ vi sites-enabled/000-default
```

*And I change the location pointing to my folders in*

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/foo/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/user/foo/>
```

What is the ***default location of Apache2 web root*** where if I would just copy my files the Apache server would pick it. For **running hundreds of files through Apache2 each and every time I keep doing the above steps of changing the location manually**. Is there any other best way of doing it.

*It would be great if anyone could help me out.*

Answer (score 0):

If do an ls -l inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ you'll see that 000-default is a symlink to /etc/apache2/sites-available/. The idea being that you create site definition files in sites-enabled, then symlink to them from sites-available... making it very simple to enable and disable sites as needed.

In fact, Ubuntu provides the a2ensite command to enable sites, and a2dissite to disable sites. This means all you have to do is create the vhost file in sites-available, then run a2ensite to enable it.

Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html for more details.